# You also can reach us easily Or You also can reach TO us easily

Tags: transitivity

"You also can reach us easily"

"You also can reach to us easily"

Using the "to" would be grammatical?

Added : When we ask them to email us or call us - "You also can reach (to) us easily by [email] or [the number]"

Comment: "You also can reach to us easily." seems grammatical, but it doesn't sound right or make logical sense to me. Can you add some context? However you can say "You also can reach *out* to us easily."

Comment: Thanks I have added the whole sentence what I'm thinking of. "You also can reach (to) us easily by [email] or [the number]" What in this case?

Answer (score 6):

*Reach* is most often used as a transitive verb, meaning that it takes a direct object, without the need of a preposition:

> I can't reach the apple from here.
>
> Finally we reached the shore.
>
> You can reach me anytime on my cellphone.

In all of the senses where someone is trying to physically or metaphorically establish contact with a remote object, no preposition is used; so putting the "to" in, as per your example, is ungrammatical.

Of course there are ways to use *reach* where the "to" can be expected, particularly when describing the range of someone's grasp or the size of some object (by relating how close it comes to some other object):

> My 6-year-old can reach all the way to the 3rd shelf of the fridge.
>
> The algae bloom on the lake reaches to the far shore.

Comment: Thanks. The examples makes easy to understand. What if the sentence is a bit like this? "You also can reach (to) us easily by [email] or [the number]" Should we use the "to"?

Comment: In that case you should not use the 'to'.

Answer (score 0):

In English, it's normal that some prepositions are omitted, for example

> I will send you a text message.

Which is the same as

> I will send *to* you a text message.

Or

> I will send a text message *to* you.

In the first sentence, the preposition *to* is omitted.

Your example is not quite clear, it would be better if you give me the context. For now, I think they are both grammatically correct. But as user3169 says, it might not make sense.

Comment: Hmm. Depending on the dialect, _I will send to you some text message_ might be stilted, I can say that in mine (AusE) it would be. In fact, saying _I will send you __some__ text message_ rather than ___a__ text message_, for instance, seems highly marked to me.

Comment: Thx. It should be "a text message" or "some text messages"

Comment: Great. In this case can we omit or using it would be ok? "You also can reach (to) us easily by [email] or [the number]"

Comment: That's not the same as this case. "us" is the direct object of "reach". Also, the idiomatic way of saying it is "I will send a text message to you".

Answer (score 0):

If you look "reach" up in the [M-W dictionary](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/reach), you'll see the definition 2c(2):

> to get up to or as far as : come to
> your letter reached me yesterday
> his voice reached the last rows
> they hoped to reach an agreement

This is listed as a transitive meaning, so no preposition is needed. And in the examples given, there indeed isn't  a preposition.